# nodejs, module in the browser - Uncaught ReferenceError: buffer is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So i have been messing around with parsing some Counter-strike demo's in Nodejs, using [jsgo](https://github.com/CSGO-Analysis/) - and everything is great. But i would like to be able to parse demo's in the browser aswell (and according to the github it should work in the browser aswell).

I made sure to include jsgo-src file, and tried out one of the [examples](https://github.com/CSGO-Analysis/jsgo/blob/master/examples/round_scores.browser.html) but then get the following error

```
<input type="file" id="demo" name="demo" style="display: none" />
    <br />
    <script>
        $(function() {

            $('#demo').show().change(function(e) {

                if (e.target.files.length > 0) {

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function() {

                        var previousRound = 0;

                        var myDemo = new jsgo.Demo().
                        on('game.round_end', function(event) {

                            console.log('ROUND ' + (previousRound + 1));

                            previousRound = 0;
                            var teams = this.getTeams();

                            for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {

                                var team = teams[i];
                                var side = team.getSide();

                                if (side == 'TERRORIST' || side == 'CT') {
                                    console.log(team.getSide() + ' (' + teams[i].getClanName() + '): ' + team.getScore());
                                    previousRound += team.getScore();
                                }
                            }

                            console.log('--------');

                        }).
                        parse(new Uint8Array(reader.result));

                    }
                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

- Uncaught ReferenceError: buffer is not defined

As i understand it, Buffer is not a part of the browser, so i should be able to use the nodejs module [browserify](https://browserify.org/) and then simply make sure that i was include aswell - it seemed to work at first, until i got the following error:

```
var buffer = require('buffer');
```

- Uncaught TypeError: buffer.writeUInt8 is not a function

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, when browserify'ing the Buffer module from nodejs, do i need to change something in the jsgo.js src? or maybe its the wrong way im trying to get this nodejs module to work in my browser? :)

Comment: The last change made to the repo is 7 Years old. You sure you want to revive a dead one? On the original repo there are even a message: "Sorry for my lack of updates on this. I'm aware its not working with latest demo files. I've been extremely busy - I'll be launching a new version soon" And nothing happend.

Comment: well you are obviously right about it being very old, but it works flawlessly in nodejs - but you might be right, and i should see if i can find something else!